# Visual studio addin - window children can't get focus

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, sdk

I have some addin for VS2010 which displays window with some many panels. I'm using Avalon docking manager to handle all panels manipulation.

My problem is that all items (listboxs or items control) within the my window can't get focus, even when I'm clicking on them directly. this problem is expressed when i'm trying to use mouse wheel in order to scroll the scrollViews in my window.

Just want to mention that when I'm using my window in a stand alone application (not as VS2010 addin) everything works.

Any idea? Is this Avalon problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be bug of Avalon.
Updating to latest version fix the problem.